# Bind to collection commands in data template

Tags: wpf, binding, command, datatemplate

I have a list box with a collection as its data context and I have defined a data template to have specific view of collection items.

I want to execute commands at the collection level that may apply to some items or not and want to use them in data template. There are a lot of code to insert, but hope that this picture give you the general idea.

[image]

How can I define such commands in data templates that binds to command at collection level and how to know which item has sent the command?

Comment: Its a bit difficult to understand what you mean without any code. Is the collection class your own and you added commands to it?

Comment: more importent is how you fire the commands? click on the list item? button on the data template?

Comment: @ Orchestrator : Yes, Actually there are some methods in the collection that I'm creating Relay Commands in View Model to Run it.

Comment: @ ZSH : For example by Checking a Radio Button or triggering textChanged event of a text box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution in the following article :

[Command Binding inside DataTemplate in Parent-Child Scenario in an MVVM Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159939/Command-Binding-inside-DataTemplate-in-Parent-Chil)

By Amit Kumar Dutta